# Loop through dates and add data to it

Tags: php, loops, date

I want to list all the dates between 2 dates and in that loop, I want to insert data from my database.

As it is right now, the loop lists the same dates and times but with different strings.

```
2018-02-20 23:55   Took 2 pills
2018-02-20 23:55   Refilled with 50 pills
2018-02-20 23:55   Took 2 pills
2018-02-20 23:55   Took 2 pills
2018-02-20 23:55   Took 2 pills
2018-02-20 23:55   Refilled with 40 pills
```

If I remove the while loop, it looks like this:

```
2018-02-05 18:03   Took 2 pills
2018-02-03 12:37   Refilled with 50 pills
2018-02-02 15:00   Took 2 pills
2018-02-01 13:45   Took 2 pills
2018-01-31 16:34   Took 2 pills
2018-01-31 11:02   Refilled with 40 pills
```

I want it to list like this:

```
2018-02-05 18:03   Took 2 pills
2018-02-04   Took 0 pills
2018-02-03 12:37   Refilled with 50 pills
2018-02-02 15:00   Took 2 pills
2018-02-01 13:45   Took 2 pills
2018-01-31   Took 2 pills at 16:34 and refilled with 40 pills at 11:02
```

Here's how the loops looks like:

```
# LOOP
foreach($get_activity AS $activity) {

    # LOOP
    while($date_start != $date_end) {

        # VARIABLE
        $date_start += 86400;


        # ITEMS
        echo '<div>';

            # DATE & TIME
            echo '<div class="datetime">';
                echo datetime($activity['datetime_occured']);
                # echo date('Y-m-d', $date_start);
            echo '</div>';


            # ACTIVITY
            echo '<div class="string">';

                # IF
                if($activity['data_pills_taken'] != 0) {
                    echo 'Tog <span>'.$activity['data_pills_taken'].'</span> tablett'.($activity['data_pills_taken'] == 1 ? '' : 'er');

                # IF
                } elseif($activity['data_pills_total'] != 0) {
                    echo 'Fyllde på med <span>'.$activity['data_pills_total'].'</span> tablett'.($activity['data_pills_total'] == 1 ? '' : 'er');
                }

            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div>';

    }

}
```

Complete source code: https://gist.github.com/edgren/585d8d1d67c93979003022d8c3cbf5f2

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You want to retrieve data from a database and *inject* new stuff into the middle of the output of the retrieved data? **Without** updating the database itself, correct?

Comment: I want to list all the dates within a loop from and to specific dates. Within this loop, I want to add data to these dates. If any data for a date exists, add time and a string to it. If more than 1 data exists for a date, add the time within the string. No updates to the database :) Only fetching the data from the database.